# Convert unwellformatted JSON to C# class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I got a C# Class:

```
public class JsonAttachmentModel
{
    public Guid AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ExtentionName { get; set; }
}
```

and the JSON i retrieve is unwellformatted, it is altogether in one string, like:

```
{"success":false,"message":"The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large."},
{"success":true,"attachmentId":"dba60830-46fd-4f51-9cd5-3c20df03988d","fileName":"bz1_20121206113251.PNG","extentionName":".PNG"},
{"success":true,"attachmentId":"3cae3f50-7d70-4183-9a69-80cb6d619dbd","fileName":"bz2_20121206113251.PNG","extentionName":".PNG"},
{"success":true,"attachmentId":"b6c8a524-4f46-4a7a-bcda-70042cb4ca92","fileName":"IammorethanOneKb123_20121206113251.txt","extentionName":".txt"},
{"success":true,"attachmentId":"994dfb9c-a185-4c51-b1f4-1017f991740d","fileName":"Iamonekb_20121206113251.txt","extentionName":".txt"}
```

So, my question is :

How can I convert this string to `List<JsonAttachmentModel>`, with the items which only match  "success": true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). Check out the Serialization/Deserialization examples from [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/).

Example from the above documentation -

```
string json = @"[
    {
        'Name': 'Product 1',
        'ExpiryDate': '2000-12-29T00:00Z',
        'Price': 99.95,
        'Sizes': null
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Product 2',
        'ExpiryDate': '2009-07-31T00:00Z',
        'Price': 12.50,
        'Sizes': null
    }
]";

List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(products.Count);
// 2

Product p1 = products[0];

Console.WriteLine(p1.Name);
// Product 1
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this. It works very nice. Thank you very much! You save me at least 3 working hour on this:)